# How to link custom results in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, linker

My first time here an a newbee in Drupal and programming .

So I have a problem I need to some help with.

```
    function query_results($searchstring, $datefrom) {
    $tidresult = db_query("SELECT tid FROM {term_data} WHERE LOWER(name) = '%s'", strtolower($searchstring));

    $resultarray = array();
    while ($obj = db_fetch_object($tidresult)) {
        $tid = $obj->tid;

        $noderesults = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n
                                                        INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON tn.nid = n.nid
                                                            WHERE tn.tid='%s'", $tid);
        while ($nodeobj = db_fetch_object($noderesults)) {
            $resultarray[$nodeobj->nid] = $nodeobj->title;
        }
    }


        $header = array(
        array('data' => 'Nr.'),
        array('data' => 'Name'),
    );

$rows = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($resultarray as $nid => $title) {
        $i++;
        $rows[] = array('data' =>
          array(
                $i,
                $title,
            ),
        );

    }


    $output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
    print theme("page", $output);
}
```

It's driving me crazy , i dint put all of the search code but it takes taxonomy tags from the database ( you type in textbox that has autocomplete, '$searchstring' ) and date ( you choose a time line like one day , yesterday ect. ,   '$datefrom').

For example reasons lets say it looks like this [example](http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/files/blogimg/truncate_drupal_view_node_title-5.png) when you click search.

I can't post my one pictures but I just gives me the titles ( like above but the are not listed) that I cannot click to lead me to the content.

But I wont it to look like result that is like content ( story ) so you have a clickable Title and some description , like this [click to see example](http://thinkclay.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/drupal_5_screenshot.png) 
where it says lorem ipsum and that text belowe.

If it is hard to make like in the picture can someone show me just how to make( like in the first picture) the results that are non clickable titles into clickable links that lead me to the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get linked titles you need to use the `l()` function.

looking at the code you provided, I am not entirely sure how you are getting any results since you save the titles in `$resultArray` but use `$rows` when rendering the table.

Unless, $rows is specified somewhere else, `$resultarray[$nodeobj->nid] = $nodeobj->title;` should become `$rows[$nodeobj->nid] = $nodeobj->title;`
To make it match your table header, you need to add another 'cell' for the number column

```
$rows[$nodeobj->nid] = array(
  $count++,
  l($nodeobj->title, 'node/'.$nodeobj->nid)
);
```

To provide the excerpt too, you need to join the node_revisions table and get either the body or teaser column, then add it to your rows like this:

```
$rows[$nodeobj->nid] = array(
  $count++,
  '<h2>'. l($nodeobj->title, 'node/'.$nodeobj->nid) .'</h2>'. $nodeobj->teaser
);
```

assuming you get the teaser.

**EDIT**
the previous answer still holds. You can also simplify the code a bit by processing $rows straight in the $noderesults loop.

function query_results($searchstring, $datefrom) {
        $tidresult = db_query("SELECT tid FROM {term_data} WHERE LOWER(name) = '%s'", strtolower($searchstring));

```
    $rows   = array();
    $count  = 0;

    while ($obj = db_fetch_object($tidresult)) {
      $tid = $obj->tid;

      $noderesults = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n "
                             ."INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON tn.nid = n.nid "
                             ."WHERE tn.tid='%s'", $tid);

      while ($nodeobj = db_fetch_object($noderesults)) {
        $rows[] = array(
          ++$count,
          l($nodeobj->title, 'node/'. $nodeobj->title)
        );
      }
    }

    $header = array(
      array('data' => 'Nr.'),
      array('data' => 'Name'),
    );


    $output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
    print theme("page", $output);
}
```

-OR-

move it all in one query (note: I did not get a chance to test this, but I usually get it right the first time):

```
function query_results($searchstring, $datefrom) {

  $rows   = array();
  $count  = 0;

  $results = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title 
                       FROM {node} n 
                       INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON tn.nid = n.nid 
                       WHERE tn.tid IN (SELECT tid FROM {term_data} WHERE LOWER(name) = '%s')", strtolower($searchstring));


  while ($nodeobj = db_fetch_object($results)) {
    $rows[] = array(
      ++$count,
      l($nodeobj->title, 'node/'. $nodeobj->title)
    );
  }

  $header = array(
    array('data' => 'Nr.'),
    array('data' => 'Name'),
  );


  $output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
  print theme("page", $output);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering , I put the missing code. I pasted an older version of my code so the complete one is up there now .